# Pass oauth header in soap call with erlang detergent library

Tags: soap, erlang, salesforce, elixir

I am using [detergent](https://github.com/devinus/detergent) to make soap call to salesforce soap api.
I want to call its function call/4 but it fails:

```
:detergent.call("metadata.wsdl", "describeMetadata", ["37.0"], [{'sessionId',token.access_token}])


** (exit) an exception was raised:
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in :erlsom_write.processAnyAttributes/4
    src/erlsom_write.erl:501: :erlsom_write.processAnyAttributes('ok', [], [{:ns, 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/', 'soap', :unqualified}, {:ns, 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata', 'p', :qualified}, {:ns, 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', 'xsd', :qualified}], {[{'soap', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'}], 0})
    src/erlsom_write.erl:325: :erlsom_write.processAlternativeValue/8
```

What is the expected format of the header syntax to pass token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using [`detergent.call/4`](https://github.com/devinus/detergent/blob/master/src/detergent.erl#L97) that expects the last parameter to be a [`#call_opts`](https://github.com/devinus/detergent/blob/master/include/detergent.hrl#L6). You are passing a list [consisting of single tuple] and the function clause could not be matched.

I am not sure about what exactly you are to pass there (see the [`#call_opts` definition](https://github.com/devinus/detergent/blob/master/include/detergent.hrl#L6),) but I believe something like the below should do the trick:

```
:detergent.call(
  "metadata.wsdl",
  "describeMetadata",
  ["37.0"],
  #call_opts{http_client_options=[{'sessionId',token.access_token}]}
)
```

Comment: There's another `call/4` below that one (line 113) which is probably what OP wants to call and not the `call_opts` one. (Also, the code you pasted uses Erlang style record syntax.)

Comment: @Dogbert a list of one tuple does not look like something to be called `Msg` either. Also, since the OP was erlang and the library is erlang, I used erlang syntax, yes.